# sample UART code to read from UART2 on ELB-REV4

Tags: serial-port

I need sample c code to read from UART2 with baudrate of 3Mbps on ELB-REV4 device.

i tried some example code but did not work

I expect the Data baud or UART2 to be 3Mbps which i can see using oscilloscope.

issue is as soon as i set UART2 baudrate to 3000000. And on oscilloscope i see the baudrate still is 115200.

Comment: What example code did you try? What happened when it didn't work, did it do nothing or something other than you expected? You should edit your question to include these points. If you leave your question as is, it's too broad for this site's format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On ELB-REV4 /dev/ttyS2 represents UART2 and use /dev/ttyS0 for UART0 use the below code which outputs 101010 you can see on oscilloscope and measure the baudrate.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <string.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <unistd.h>
 #include <fcntl.h>
 #include <termios.h>
 #include <ctype.h>
 #include <errno.h>

 struct termios options;
 int fd;
 int status;
 char buf[10];
 unsigned char rx_buffer[10];
 int main(void) 
        {
           fd = open("/dev/ttyS2", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);



      if (fd < 0) 
        {
           printf("Error opening serial port\n");
           exit(1);
        }



      bzero( & options, sizeof(options));
        options.c_cflag = B3000000 | CS8 | CLOCAL | CREAD | IGNPAR | PARODD | PARENB; //8bit, Odd parity, 
        tcflush(fd, TCIFLUSH);
        tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, & options);

    while (1) 
    {
buf[0] = 0x55; //pattern
status = write(fd, & buf[0], 1);

    if (status < 0) 
    {


     printf("Write error - %s \n", strerror(errno));
        exit(1);
    }


     usleep(1000000);
        printf("Sending 0x55 to /dev/ttyS2 port\n");
    }

    }
```

Comment: thanks saurabh let me try it. i think i was setting this value to options.c_cflag = 3000000 but i did not knew i need to append B.

Comment: I think it is working i am able to measure the baudrate on oscilloscope thanks again